# Operation failed sending fax from windows service

Tags: c#, permissions, windows-services, fax

I wrote a C# COM wrapper to use FAXCOMEXLib. It works well from a Windows console application and places the fax into the Windows Fax Service queue. However after I placed the same code into a windows service, I receive back a COM exception "Operation failed" with error code -2147023741. Converting -2147023741 using Windows Programmer Calculator from Dec to Hex results in: 80070483. Deciphering the error code reveals that the error relates to Win32 (the character 7 at the beginning). To get the actual error message, the code of the error (the last part, 0x483) converted into a decimal results in 1155. Executing net helpmsg 1155 results in "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation". The fax attachment is a JPG file. I checked the file associations using the command reg query hkcr\jpegfile /s and the printto command is defined to use Windows Image and Fax viewer dll ("%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\shimgvw.dll",ImageView_PrintTo /pt %1 %2 %3 %4).

This is running on a Windows 8.1 64-bit machine and both the console and the windows service were built with AnyCPU setting. Could this be a permissions issue, and how to tell? What's causing the Windows Service to fail and the console application to work?

Comment: What is the account your service is running? HKCR is not available from Local System or System Service accounts.

Comment: I've tried running it as Administrator (.\Administrator in the windows service Log On tab)  --> same error occurs

Comment: Hello @AlexanderLiberson you continues with the errors?

Comment: Has anyone solved this issue. I seem to be having the same problem.